# 19.04 false gid for user

Tags: permissions, 19.04

yesterday i made a clean install of ubuntu19.04. Over /etc/fstab I mount my debianhome and make a bind mount to an folder.

In both systems the 1.user is the same name.

but I was suprised which permissions are  ubuntu shown in the folder.

```
ls -al jd2/
total 12784
drwxr-xr-x  18 alex sambashare    4096 Mär 20  2019  .
drwxr-xr-x  22 alex alex          4096 Okt  28 08:23  ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 alex sambashare    4096 Okt  10  2016  .install4j
-rw-r--r--   1 alex sambashare 7950765 Mär 20  2019  Core.jar
---snip
```

I boot debian, but the gid is 1000 from my user, all okay there.

```
grep samba /etc/group
sambashare:x:1000:alex
```

and

```
id 
uid=1000(alex) gid=1001(alex) groups=1001(alex),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),117(lpadmin),1000(sambashare)
```

How can I fix it, without destroying the whole system?

```
sudo groupdel sambashare
```

and

```
sudo groupmod -g 1000 alex
```

Have I afterwards to change the rights in my $HOME? is think so.

```
stat .bashrc 
  File: .bashrc
  Size: 3771            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 1703939     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    alex)   Gid: ( 1001/    alex)
Access: 2019-10-27 11:13:25.003912078 +0100
Modify: 2019-04-04 05:11:47.000000000 +0200
Change: 2019-10-27 10:59:25.817456367 +0100
 Birth: -
```

My question was already the answer.

```
id
uid=1000(alex) gid=1000(alex) Gruppen=1000(alex),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),117(lpadmin)
alex@Guilmon:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can't rename "alex" to "alex" so you need to rename "1001" to "1000" instead. This answer appears to work for you:

- [Change gid of a specific group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33874/200094)

Read the entire Q&A but in summary (if you agree it works for you) use:

```
find / -gid 1001 ! -type l -exec chgrp 1000 {} \;
```

You might also want to change the group name for GID 1001 to "alex2". This will make it easier to spot files you may have missed.

Comment: Nice try, but GID 1000 was blocked by group sambashare. I had to remove the group  first.

Comment: @nobody Sorry I've never used `samba` but that might be the first problem to solve and the GID the second problem.

Comment: Samba is not installt. Only a lonely lib. maybe an error in  calamares. It is fixed, thank you.